# If $G$ and $N$ are soluble, then $G/N$ is soluble

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. If both $G$ and $N$ are soluble, then $G/N$ is also soluble.

My attempt:

$G$ is soluble, so there exists a subnormal series $1=G_0\subset ... \subset G_n=G$. I know from a previous proof in my textbook that by setting $N_i = G_i\subset N$, then we can find a subnormal series $1=N_0(=G_{i_0})\subset N_1(=G_{i_1})\subset...\subset G_{i_m}\subset N$ where $i_j\in\{1,...,n\}$. But I don't know where to go from here.

Somehow I want to gain a new subnorma series for $G/N$

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of the result you asked about in your previous question. In fact, you don't even need that $N$ is solvable.

Comment: would this be by the quotient map $\phi: G\rightarrow G/N$ which is a group homomorphism, and hence $Im(\phi)$ is soluble

Comment: But what is there to suggest that $Im(\phi)=G/N$

Comment: The "natural" homomorphism $\phi :G \to G/N$ has $\phi(g) = gN$ for each $g \in G$, so it is obviously surjective.

Comment: But did I really need to use the fact that $N$ is soluble?

Comment: No, as I said in the first comment above, you don't need that $N$ is solvable. It is the other way round that you would need this: if $N$ and $G/N$ are both solvable, then $G$ is.

Comment: Your first line of your attempt is confusing: what you wrote there isn't related to being soluble. You **need** the factors $\;Gi/G_{i-1}\;$ to be *abelian* ...

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that if $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ is a group homomorphism and $G$ is soluble, then so is $Im(\phi)$

Let $\phi$ be the quotient map, $\phi:G\rightarrow G/N$ s.t $\phi(g)=gN$. The map is clearly a group homomorphism, hence $Im(\phi)=G/N$ is soluble